FFMPEG unable to stream videos frame by frame to RTMP Youtube Live stream using Python
I need to open a locally stored video, process it frame by frame and send it to YouTube live RTMP stream. I am able to do it using FFMPEG in command line terminal but unable to do it using Python. In Python on console, it shows stream is properly sent but on YouTube Live control room it shows no data. I tried all other tools like Vidgear, Gstreamer etc. But most of them use FFMPEG backend and it does not work.
Here is my command to directly send video from .mp4 source file that works properly on terminal and video is streamed on YouTube Live control room -
ffmpeg -re -i "video.mp4" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/youtube-key
My Python program which reads and send video frame by frame shows everything is fine on console but YouTube shows No Data -
import cv2
import subprocess

# Path to your video file
video_path = "video.mp4"

# FFmpeg command to stream to YouTube
rtmp_url = "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/youtube-key"
ffmpeg_command = [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-y',  # Overwrite output files without asking
    '-f', 'rawvideo',
    '-pixel_format', 'bgr24',
    '-video_size', '1280x720',  # Change according to your video resolution
    '-framerate', '30',  # Frame rate
    '-i', '-',  # Input from stdin
    '-c:v', 'libx264',
    '-preset', 'veryfast',
    '-maxrate', '3000k',
    '-bufsize', '6000k',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
    '-f', 'flv',
    rtmp_url
]

# Start FFmpeg process
ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# Open video with OpenCV
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open video.")
    exit()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break  # End of video

    # Write the frame to FFmpeg's stdin
    ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())

# Cleanup
cap.release()
ffmpeg_process.stdin.close()
ffmpeg_process.wait()

Console output -

FFMPEG Build info -

I tried in Linux and Windows both and got same results. In the python program, I am not processing frames now but in future I will do it. I just want to stream video frame by frame as of now so that I can do the processing in future. Please help!!!

"Failed to update header with ..." is the reason likely why it's not working. Can you try different format?

I did not downvote but images of code/data are not allowed. If your question is about ffmpeg and it's command line usage, that's off topic. Later, I guess, I'll read your question.

@Rob its not any image of code/data. Its the terminal output showing OpenCV build info. Its useful and important for debugging and checking version issues. I have added my code in code blocks. FFMPEG allows CLI usage. Its not offtopic as python is also there. Please read the question properly and then upvote it. Downvoting useful questions discourages developers.

@kesh Its normal ffmpeg output.

Why do you build the list for Popen with different instructions from the CLI?

in CLI version, i am sending video directly from source while in popen python, i need to read and send video frame by frame. @pierpy Please go through the question in detail.
